# JArray Objects to a Class with array property

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a service that consumes API methods and it returns a json string. I have a base response object below:

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public bool HasError { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

and a generic type parser

```
 Task<R> ParseResponse<R>(HttpResponseMessage response) where R : BaseResponse,  new()
```

That returns:

```
 return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<R>(responseText);
```

Note that I don't have control over the response of the api. So I get this response, an array of objects.

```
 [{"created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","updated":null,"name":"Test 1","decscription":null,"id":1},{"created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","updated":null,"name":"Test 2","decscription":null,"id":2},{"created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","updated":null,"name":"Test 3","decscription":null,"id":3},{"created":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","updated":null,"name":"Test 4","decscription":null,"id":4}]
```

The problem is I would like to parse it to this class:

```
public class TestResponse : BaseResponse
{
    public Test[] Tests { get; set; }
}
```

The `HasError` and `Message` will have a value when an error occurred on the server or the api returned a Bad Request etc.

Any information will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you want for `HasError` and `Message`?  They are not present in the JSON.

Comment: @dbc The `HasError` and `Message` will have a value when an error occured on the server or the api returned a `Bad Request` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, it sounds as though a successful response will appear as a JSON array, but if an error occurs then a JSON object will be returned with an error flag and message.  In order to parse both possible responses, you can create a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that checks whether the received JSON is an array or an object, and proceeds accordingly:

```
public class TestResponseConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(TestResponse);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            // A valid response.  Populare the Tests array.
            var tests = serializer.Deserialize<Test[]>(reader);
            return new TestResponse { Tests = tests };
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            // An error response.  Populate HasError and Message
            var response = new TestResponse();
            serializer.Populate(reader, response);
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected reader.TokenType: " + reader.TokenType);
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var test = (TestResponse)value;
        if (test.HasError && test.Tests != null && test.Tests.Length > 0)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, new { HasError = test.HasError, Message = test.Message, Tests = test.Tests });
        }
        else if (test.HasError || test.Tests == null)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, new { HasError = test.HasError, Message = test.Message });
        }
        else
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, test.Tests);
        }
    }
}
```

Then apply it to the class using [`JsonConverterAttribute`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) like so:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(TestResponseConverter))]
public class TestResponse : BaseResponse
{
    public Test[] Tests { get; set; }
}
```

Or add it to [`JsonSerializerSettings`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) like so:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new[] { new TestResponseConverter() } };
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<R>(responseText, settings);
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LeW8SW).